# How are all the ways a variable is exposed in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I have used libraries like handlebars before for templating. In handlebars any variables exposed from the javascript could be used in HTML using the double curly braces {{}}. I saw the curly braces was used in a similar way in AngularJS but it was not the only way to get the variables as shown below.

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
   <h1>{{ title }}</h1> //Here title is inside curly braces like handlebars
   <h2>{{ promo }}</h2>
   <div ng-repeat="product in products" class="col-md-6"> //here products is inside quotations without curly braces
    <img ng-src="{{product.cover}}"> //here product.cover is inside quotations with curly braces.
    <app-info info="move"></app-info> //here move is inside quotations without curly braces. app-info is a directive created in the app.
```

This confuses me a lot and I cannot easily figure out where to use the {{ }} and where not to use them.  Is there a basic set of rules I could follow to make it easier? Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: basicly the curly thingys are for html whenever you use ng-... you dont need the curlys and in your controller the value is $scope.something in ng-change="something = flase" and in html its <p>{{somethin}}</p>

Comment: Thanks but why does ng-src have curly braces?

Comment: from the documentation {{}} on ng-src and ng-href are the correct way to do it

Comment: @stackg91 It just depend on the directive use of the var. If it want a string it can makes you use braces. If it want the var reference you will not have to use braces. You can check my answer for more informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html :

```
<div> This is some regular text your need {{interpretThis}} to say angular that you want to interpret that part </div>

//this is a regular attribute, angular don't know that he should interpret
<div class="{{interpretThis}}"></div>
```

Now about the directives :

When you define a directive you can add an isolated scope and you will bind the var from the HTML.

Whenever you need or not to use the brace depends on the definition.

```
 scope:{
    //Will interpret
    "this": "=",
    //Will interpret as a string
    "that": "@"
 }

 <my-directive this="interpretThis" that="{{interpretThat}}"></my-directive>
```

"that" will contain the string interpretation of {{interpretThat}} and not the var.

Note that almost all the angular built in directive use the "=" type. So in 99% of the angular directives you will not have to use braces.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Double curly braces (`{{}}`) indicate an [angular expression, which is evaluated by angulars own parser](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

[When defining a directive one can define what kind of parameters the directive gets](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object) - data (no braces, only actual js data) or plain text (which can be parsed with the angular parser before passing by using double curly braces).

When in doubt, you can always check the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api) to see if you need to pass an expression or not. For [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) for example it states that you have to pass a template (meaning an expression).